# subscript out of bounds error when I use R to do an regression analysis

Tags: r, error-handling

When I run the code below I receive:

```
"Error in coef(summary(linear))[6, 1] : subscript out of bounds
```

Here is the code I run:

```
setwd("E:/test_analysis/TNBC")

data=read.table("gene_snp_regression.csv",header=T,sep=",")
result <- NULL
for (i in 10:708){  
  linear <- lm(data[, 6] ~ 
                 data[,2]+data[,3]+data[,4]+data[,5]+data[,i], data = data)
  
  x.inv <- try(solve(coef(summary(linear))[6,4]),silent = TRUE)
  if ("try-error" %in% class(x.inv)) pvalue <- "NA"
  else pvalue <- coef(summary(linear))[6,4]
  
  beta <-  coef(summary(linear))[6,1]
  
  X <- cbind(beta, pvalue)
  
  result <- rbind(result, X)    
}
write.csv(result,"sig1_genesnp.csv",row.names = T, quote = F)
```

I wanna get the Estimate value "data[, i]"

```
                   Estimate Std. Error    t value     Pr(>|t|)
       (Intercept) 158.98784   54.67884  2.9076665 3.959462e-03
       data[, 2]    11.72500   14.42698  0.8127131 4.171348e-01
       data[, 3]    14.22904   14.53601  0.9788822 3.285587e-01
       data[, 4]   -52.44000   13.25313 -3.9567994 9.832974e-05
       data[, 5]   -23.63112   13.88214 -1.7022681 8.991430e-02
       data[, i]    12.74142   10.06581  1.2658112 2.067270e-01
```

but after I run the code I  receive: "Error in coef(summary(linear))[6, 1] : subscript out of bounds.

### Here is the structure of coef(summary(linear))

```
str(coef(summary(linear)))
num [1:6, 1:4] 159 11.7 14.2 -52.4 -23.6 ...                     
- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:6] "(Intercept)" "data[, 2]" "data[, 3]" "data[, 4]" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:4] "Estimate" "Std. Error" "t value" "Pr(>|t|)"
```

Comment: Have you looked at the structure of `coef(summary(linear))`?

Comment: Please edit your original question.

Comment: yes,I get coef(summary(linear)) exactly like the results I pasted above. But when I run the entire code, I got the error and missed the right pvalue and Estimate value.

Comment: Can you paste the structure (`str()`)of the output?

Comment: Please don't use comments for sharing your results. Edit your original question. You could take a few minutes of your time and learn how [stackoverflow works](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: So sorry for my mistake. I have pasted the results into my original question.

Comment: Thanks. Can you discern structure from the output, because I sure can't. Please format your code/data properly.

Comment: I'm terrible sorry. This is my first time looking for help in stackoverflow. I am so thankful for your pacient and kindness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[6, 1]` should pick up sixth element in column one. This leads me to believe that something is going wrong within the loop. There are many debugging options of how to handle this.

Inside for loop you can:

(1) Inserting print statements

```
print (i) # it will let you know where the problem occurs
print(dim(coef(summary(linear)))) # see dimensions of the result
```

(2) Insert browser()

```
browser()
```

and then manually step through the code by pressing `n` (or enter) to execute a line or `c` to run the whole loop once.

In your R sessions, you can set

```
options(error = recovery)
```

and R will stop when an error occurs and will offer you to inspect various environments. At this point, you can determine the root cause of your errors by inspecting all the elements.

The pedestrian way of going about this would be to set `i` manually and step through the code, inspecting each element.